# Cannot get results Between dates in SQLite using Java PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sqlite, date, prepared-statement, between

I have been trying to get data from a table 'produccion' that has a date field called 'dia' using a between statement.

The SQL sentence I was aimig for is:

`SELECT * FROM produccion WHERE julianday(dia) BETWEEN julianday('2023-11-01') AND julianday('2023-11-31');`

The java code is quite hard to read, as I tried making the code valid for everything. I have enforced foreign keys on, but I am not going outside of the table so it should not matter.

```
    private ResultSet resultado;
    private PreparedStatement prepSentencia;

    public ResultSet pedirDatos (String[] campos, String tabla, String[][] join, String[] condicionColumna, Object[] condicionValor, String operador, String orden) throws SQLException {

        String select = "SELECT ";
        resultado=null;

        if (campos != null && tabla !=null) {
            for (int x=0; x<campos.length;x++) {
                select = select + campos[x];
                if (x+1<campos.length)
                    select = select + ", ";
            }
            select = select + " FROM "+tabla;
            if (join != null) {
                for (int tupla=0; tupla<join.length; tupla++) {
                    select = select + " INNER JOIN " + join[tupla][0] + " ON "+ tabla + "." + join[tupla][1] + " = " + join[tupla][0] + "." + join[tupla][2];
                }
            }
            // This is the where part
            if (condicionColumna!=null) {
                select = select + " WHERE " ;
                for (int i =0; i<condicionColumna.length;i++) {
                    // Usual where
                    if (condicionColumna[i] != "" && condicionColumna.length==condicionValor.length)
                        select = select + condicionColumna[i]+" = ? ";
                    // Between code goes trough here
                    else if (condicionColumna[i] != "" && condicionColumna.length==1 && condicionValor.length==2)
                        select = select+ condicionColumna[i]+" BETWEEN julianday(?) AND julianday(?) ";
                    // Verifico si hay más rotaciones y añado el and o el OR
                    if (((i+1)<condicionColumna.length))
                        select = select + " "+operador+" ";
                }
            }

            // Checks for orders
            if (!(orden==null || orden==""))
                select = select + " ORDER BY ? ";
            // Create the sentence
            prepSentencia = conexion.prepareStatement(select+";", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            
            // Fill the data
            if (condicionValor!=null ) {
                for (int i =0; i<condicionValor.length;i++) {
                    if (condicionValor[i] != "")
                        prepSentencia.setObject((i+1),condicionValor[i]);
                    if (((i+1)==condicionValor.length) && !(orden==null || orden==""))
                        prepSentencia.setString(i+2,orden);
                }
            } else if (!(orden==null || orden==""))
                prepSentencia.setString(1,orden);
            resultado = prepSentencia.executeQuery();
        }
        else
            throw new SQLException ("I need input data");
        return resultado;
    }
```

Data input:

`pedirDatos(new String[] {"*"}, "produccion",null,new String[] {"julianday(dia)"},new String[] {"'2023-11-01'","'2023-11-31'"},"AND",null);`

The table is formed before with a statement as:

```
regularstatement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS produccion(\n"
        + " id_produccion INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n"
        + " dia TEXT NOT NULL,\n"
        + " hora TEXT NOT NULL,\n"
        + " cantidad REAL NOT NULL,\n"
        + " num_animales INTEGER NOT NULL,\n"
        + " media_por_animal INTEGER,\n"
        + " incidencias TEXT \n"
        + ");");
```

I know there is date field in SQLite, so i made it text.

I was debugging and I found that the program goes properly trough all the code, and debugging the resultset contains the stmt part with this info:

SELECT * FROM produccion WHERE julianday(dia, 'utc') BETWEEN julianday(?) AND julianday(?) ;
parameters=['2023-11-01', '2023-11-31']

I have verified that i have two rows in the table with the date 2023-11-17

So it seems that I am inyecting the data properly in the prepared statement, and I feel like the sentence is correct. I have no idea why i am not getting results as I have been using this with success in the rest of the program.

I have also tried using julianday(data,'utc'), strftime(), date() and using direclty the dates. I looked at https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and could not make it work.

What kills me, is that using an online viewer (https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/) i can make the SQL work, but when running java it returns no data when it should.

Edit: to clarify, I started having this problem when I tried `SELECT * FROM 'produccion' WHERE dia BETWEEN '2023-11-01' AND '2023-11-30'` and did not work.

Edit2: corrected julianday as forpas commented. Still no data returned.
Added proof that there is data in the database file
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us31d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` placeholders in your query are replaced by the parameters `julianday('2023-11-01')` and `julianday('2023-11-31')` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM produccion 
WHERE julianday(dia) BETWEEN 'julianday('2023-11-01')' AND 'julianday('2023-11-31')';
```

(with the single quotes properly escaped) because you pass them as strings.

Instead you should write the query:

```
SELECT * FROM produccion 
WHERE julianday(dia) BETWEEN julianday(?) AND julianday(?);
```

and pass the parameters `'2023-11-01'` and `'2023-11-30'` (not `'2023-11-31'` because there are only 30 days in November).

But, why do you use `julianday()` in your query?
If your dates are properly formated as `YYYY-MM-DD` it is simpler to write the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM produccion 
WHERE dia BETWEEN ? AND ?;
```

Edit by @PabloIglesias: I will clarify here as the coment with the solution is not visible by default and this leads to solution but can be missunderstood.

In order to pass a SQL parameter as `'2023-11-01'` when using putString, we should use `putString("2023-11-01")` and not `putString("'2023-11-01'")` as the method automatically includes the ', and was the original mistake made.

Comment: You are right about julianday, and I feel i made the same mistake with date() and the rest when I started looking for answers and used functions. The first issue I had was `SELECT * FROM 'produccion' WHERE dia BETWEEN '2023-11-01' AND '2023-11-30'` was not working either. And yes, I have my dates in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: @PabloIglesias if `SELECT * FROM 'produccion' WHERE dia BETWEEN '2023-11-01' AND '2023-11-30'` does not return any data this means that there are no data between these dates.

Comment: And here lies my problem, there is data, I confirmed it by several sources, but the query returns nothing.

Comment: @PabloIglesias then you are oing something wrong.

Comment: That something is wrong is clear to me, as I should be getting data but I have no idea why I am not getting it.

Comment: Found the problem. Thanks to you I checked again and again the input of data, as I was sending the julianday() inside the putSring and feared something similar could happen.  And indeed the problem is similar, but not the same. The data input should be: 

` pedirDatos(new String[] {"*"}, "produccion",null,new String[] {"julianday(dia)"},new String[] {"2023-11-01","2023-11-31"},"AND",null); `

To be more clear, the problem is sending to putString `"'2023-11-01'"` when it should be `"2023-11-01"`, no ' in the data